# Wrap JStree in function and pass variables does not work if function is not in the same document as caller

Tags: javascript, jstree

If my JStree initialisation function is in the same file as caller everything works, but if I move function call to html document it does not return anything. Here is the code I came up up to now:

```
function cattree(treeID, treeAncestors, treeCurrent) {
        alert(treeID + treeAncestors + treeCurrent);
        $("#"+treeID).jstree({ 
            "core" : { 
                "initially_load" : treeAncestors,
            },

            "ui" :{
                "select_limit" : 1,
                "initially_select" : [treeCurrent],
            },
            "json_data" : {
                "progressive_render" : true,
                "progressive_unload" : true,
                "ajax" : {
                    "url" : "/taxonomy/catjson",
                    "dataType": "text json",
                    "data" : function (n) { 
                        return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; 
                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ],
        });
}
```

When I move it to document I think it does not wait for document with function to load.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        cattree("demo", ['4e974c91f0282e7011000004', '4e974d92f0282ec41a00000a'], ['4e974da1f0282e2c0c000000']);
   }
   );
```

Comment: It would be timing/sequence issue. Can you provide jsfiddle sample?

Comment: I believe this was issue with calling the function before the external js was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what came up with:

cattree init in external file

```
(function () {
    if(jQuery && jQuery.jstree && jQuery.cattree) { return; }
    (function ($) {
        $.cattree = function(treeID, treeAncestors, treeCurrent) {
            //alert(treeID + treeAncestors + treeCurrent);
            //tree initialization function to possibly allow one or more tree on page.
            $("#"+treeID).jstree({ 
                "core" : { 
                    "initially_load" : treeAncestors,
                },

                "ui" :{
                    "select_limit" : 1,
                    "initially_select" : treeCurrent,
                },
                "json_data" : {
                    "progressive_render" : true,
                    "progressive_unload" : true,
                    "ajax" : {
                        "url" : "/taxonomy/catjson",
                        "dataType": "text json",
                        "data" : function (n) { 
                            return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; 
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ],
            });

        }
    })(jQuery);
})();
```

And the code in head section or I think below all html:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
    $.cattree("demo", ['4e974c91f0282e7011000004', '4e974d92f0282ec41a00000a'], ['4e974da1f0282e2c0c000000']);
    }
);
```

At the moment it works quite nicely. And I think the issue was that the function was called before everything is loaded. As before adding Jquery.cattree to if statement it was failing to recognize $.cattree as a function.